# Coq: Implementation of splitstring and proof that nothing gets deleted

Tags: coq, proof, induction

after working for a whole day on this with no success, I might get some help here.
I implemented a splitString function in Coq: It takes a String (In my case a `list ascii`) and a function `f: ascii->bool`. I want to return a list of strings (In my case a `list (list ascii)`) containing all the substrings. This means that the input string has been split at all `ascii`s where f is true. Note that my output also includes the delimiter as a string (`list ascii`) of length 1.

My first question: exists this function in a library somewhere? Many other, non-functional, programming languages I know includes this function in the default library.

I didn't found something, so I implemented it by myself:

```
Fixpoint split_string (f: ascii->bool) (z s: list ascii): list (list ascii) :=
match s with
| [] => [rev z]
| h::t => match f h with
  | true => ([rev z]++[[h]])++(split_string f [] t)
  | false => (split_string f (h::z) t)
  end
end.
```

The function needs to be called with an empty z, like `Compute split_string isWhite [] some_string.`

The clue of that List `z` is that the current string gets saved in it until a delimiter is found, then the whole string `z` gets returned. I don't see another way of solving this.

The problem with the List `z` is that, when it comes to proofing, it makes trouble.

I want to proove that, when the output of the splitString function gets flattened (in coq with `concat`) it is equal to the input, because the splitString method does not remove information. I formulated a theorem:

```
Theorem not_more_not_less_splitWhite: forall (s: list ascii),
s = concat (split_string isWhite [] s).
```

But every time when I try to solve this with induction, I get stuck because the List `z` is not empty anymore (since one char which is not white has been processed). Then I can never apply the induction hypothesis. This is how far I've made it:

```
Proof. intros s. induction s.
- simpl. reflexivity.
- simpl. destruct isWhite eqn:W.
   * simpl. rewrite <- IHs. reflexivity.
   *
```

I found myself in willing to induce in s a second time, but I think this is bullshit and does not use the power of induction. So, if the answer to my first question is no, my second question is how do I solve this, or is there a better implementation for splitString.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof of your theorem:

```
Goal forall p l buf, rev buf ++ l = concat (split_string p buf l).
Proof. 
  induction l as [ | a l IHl]. 
  - intro; now cbn.
  -  cbn; case_eq (p a); intro Ha.
   + intro buf; repeat rewrite concat_cons; now rewrite <- IHl.
   + intro buf; rewrite <- IHl; cbn; now rewrite <- app_assoc. 
Qed.
```

Please note that it worked thanks to the universal quantification on `buf` in the induction hypothesis.  It was made easier thanks to the order of
quantifications in the goal statement.

Ana's statement can be proved the same way, with a small bookkeeping sequence before the induction:

```
Goal forall p buf l, rev buf ++ l = concat (split_string p buf l).
Proof. 
  intros p buf l; revert buf.
  induction l as [ | a l IHl]. 
   (* ... *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! With your proof, I managed to proof the theorem and can now move further!

Answer (score 2):

This problem is common whenever proving things by induction about a fixpoint with an accumulator, such as yours. The standard advice is to find a stronger statement that has your desired result as a corollary. This stronger statement should be about all lists, not only the empty list. The latter should hopefully be easier to prove with induction, since the stronger statement leads to a stronger induction hypothesis.

In your case, I guess (but haven't checked) the stronger statement could be something like:

```
Theorem not_more_not_less_splitWhite_stronger: forall (z s: list ascii),
rev z ++ s = concat (split_string isWhite z s).
```

Comment: This makes totally sense. I now proofed that theorem with Pierre's answer. Thank You!